# Event context menu in full calendar?

Tags: events, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu, fullcalendar

I'm using Full calendar plugin. i add context menu on calendar, so now i try to add differnet content menu on event,,, . when user click on blank slot a different context menu show, and when user click on event a differnet context menu show..

[Live my work demo on jsfiddle click here...](http://jsfiddle.net/KEJYD/15/)

it is work properly in Mozilla. Please see live work and change there and update link... ... but thats not issue, when i right click on event id=calendar content menu show, but i want to show some different id=Event content menu on event right click... . here is my HTML code..

. here is my HTML code..

```
 <div id='calendar'  data-toggle="context" data-target="#calendar-context-menu" ></div>

 <!-- show date-->
   <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="location" class="span6" id="location"/>

 <!-- On calendar content-menu-->
 <div id="calendar-context-menu" >
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:alert(mousedowndate);">Action</a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" >Another action</a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

  <!-- Here is Event Context menu-->
     <div id="event-context-menu" >
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:alert(mousedowndate);">Eventn</a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" >Event menu</a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```